# How to resolve error after upgrading Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V`  but it does not exist. Its class, `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition`, is available from the following locations:

```
jar: ../.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinition.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:../.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition`

Comment: And, according to the stacktrace you haven't shared with us, which class.method is making the call to `setRole`? Which jar file does that class come from? --- If you want help, you need to share all relevant information, which always include the full stacktrace if the question is about an exception. Since this error is caused by jar files with mismatched versions, you should also share your dependencies from your Maven or Gradle build script.

Comment: Errors like this generally come from using incompatiblke versions of frameworks or even worse mix jars from different versions of a framework. The latter seems to be the case here.

Comment: Please share the pom.xml for this application.